# Como remover minha pergunta?

Tags: suporte, perguntas

Como faço para remover uma pergunta aqui no Stack Overflow ?

Fiz uma pergunta. Depois vi que eu deveria tê-la feito de outra forma, ou não era bem aquilo.
Então eu gostaria de remover a minha própria pergunta.
Tem como eu fazer isso?

Comment: Aproveite que você está conhecendo melhor o site agora, e faça o [tour](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour)! ;)

Comment: **Quantas perguntas você quer remover?** http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/310672/remove-my-own-question

Comment: Pode editar também se não houver respostas.

Answer (score 13):

Sim. É só clicar no link `remover` abaixo da pergunta:

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

Como pode ver, existe o link `editar` também. Se ainda não obteve resposta, pode editar sua pergunta à vontade <sup>(sem abusar)</sup> que ela irá parar na página principal atraindo a atenção. Se já houve resposta, pode editar desde que não faça a resposta ficar inválida.

Não é necessário (inclusive é proibido) criar uma nova pergunta tentando resolver o mesmo problema da pergunta antiga. Pelo que vi no seu perfil, pode ser que tenha acontecido isso.

Lembrando que se a pergunta já teve duas respostas, não pode remover. Se tiver uma resposta com votos positivos, também não pode remover. Se for uma emergência, clique no link `sinalizar` e explique a situação para os moderadores avaliarem.

Sugiro tentar melhorar a qualidade geral das suas perguntas também. Se tiver muitas perguntas removidas, sem resposta, negativadas ou sem votos positivos, pode ser banido de fazer novas perguntas. E ao contrário, quanto mais caprichar na pergunta, mais chances de receber uma resposta excelente e votos positivos de bonus.